# Can't concatenate image url with variable in Typescript Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, concatenation

I have problem with concatenating image src string with variable in TypeScript based Reactjs

I have such code in ReactJS

```
        <div id="Result" className="flex w-100 justify-around">
        {result.map((item,index)=>{
            console.log(item);
            //return /<div className="card" key={"item-"+item+index}>{item[1]['placeName']}</div>
            return (
                <div key={"item-"+item+index} className="item w-1/4 text-center text-white">
                    <div>
                        <img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photo_reference=Aap_uEA7vb0DDYVJWEaX3O-AtYp77AaswQKSGtDaimt3gt7QCNpdjp1BkdM6acJ96xTec3tsV_ZJNL_JP-lqsVxydG3nh739RE_hepOOL05tfJh2_ranjMadb3VoBYFvF0ma6S24qZ6QJUuV6sSRrhCskSBP5C1myCzsebztMfGvm7ij3gZT&key="+{apiKey}/>
                    </div>    
                    <div>
                        <p>{item[1]['placeName']}</p>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            )   
        })}
    </div>
```

But Typescript code shows identifier in + between key=" and {apiKey}
What am I doing wrong? Why + sign doesn't work in this case?

Below is a screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 1):

change :

```
<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photo_reference=Aap_uEA7vb0DDYVJWEaX3O-AtYp77AaswQKSGtDaimt3gt7QCNpdjp1BkdM6acJ96xTec3tsV_ZJNL_JP-lqsVxydG3nh739RE_hepOOL05tfJh2_ranjMadb3VoBYFvF0ma6S24qZ6QJUuV6sSRrhCskSBP5C1myCzsebztMfGvm7ij3gZT&key="+{apiKey}/>
```

to :

```
<img src=`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photo_reference=Aap_uEA7vb0DDYVJWEaX3O-AtYp77AaswQKSGtDaimt3gt7QCNpdjp1BkdM6acJ96xTec3tsV_ZJNL_JP-lqsVxydG3nh739RE_hepOOL05tfJh2_ranjMadb3VoBYFvF0ma6S24qZ6QJUuV6sSRrhCskSBP5C1myCzsebztMfGvm7ij3gZT&key=${apiKey}`/>
```